# StackExchange.Redis, use CancellationToken with IDatabase.StringGetAsync()

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have created .Net 8 version API. I'm using Azure Redis cache in the application.

The Nuget package used to interact with Azure Redis is 'StackExchange.Redis'.
To fetch the data there is function given `IDatabase.StringGetAsync()` but there is no provision to provide `CancellationToken` in this function.

How can I achieve this operation timeout capability with `StringGetAsync()` function. I want to achieve, if this GET operation take more than 1 second then the call be aborted.

Comment: This isn't yet supported by the library -> [#1039](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1039). You could maybe implement it in your Wrapper.

Comment: Hi @DenisMicheal, What is the best way to implement the wrapper, can you please provide the reference